# SQL Syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: sql

Here is the code I'm running into an error with:

```
FROM
    IndexPID
    INNER JOIN Demographics ON
        IndexPID.NDoc_Number = Demographics.NDoc_Number,
    PatientSupply
    INNER JOIN Demographics ON
        PatientSupply.NDocNum = Demographics.NDoc_Number
```

I also tried it this way:

```
FROM
    IndexPID, PatientSupply
    INNER JOIN Demographics ON
        IndexPID.NDoc_Number = Demographics.NDoc_Number
    INNER JOIN Demographics ON
        PatientSupply.NDocNum = Demographics.NDoc_Number
```

But no cigar. Anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: IndexPID, Demographics and Patient Supply are tables. I need to join Demographics to IndexPID and Patient Supply on their NDoc_Number fields

Comment: The error is because you're just randomly throwing the name "PatientSupply" in random places.  If it's a table name, it needs to be joined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close:

```
FROM IndexPID
INNER JOIN Demographics 
   ON IndexPID.NDoc_Number = Demographics.NDoc_Number
INNER JOIN PatientSupply
   ON Demographics.NDoc_Number = PatientSupply.NDocNum
```

Answer (score 4):

would be easier if you posted the whole SQL!

Try

```
FROM
IndexPID
INNER JOIN Demographics ON
    IndexPID.NDoc_Number = Demographics.NDoc_Number
INNER JOIN PatientSupply ON
    PatientSupply.NDocNum = Demographics.NDoc_Number
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing implicit (comma-separated) and explicit `JOIN`s in an odd way here.  It should look like the following, using explicit `INNER JOIN`s only, with no commas between table names or `ON` clauses:

```
FROM
  IndexPID
  INNER JOIN Demographics 
    ON IndexPID.Ndoc_Number = Demographics.NDoc_Number
  INNER JOIN PatientSupply 
    ON PatientSupply.NDocNum = Demographics.NDoc_Number
```

Answer (score 1):

You uses inner join so you can use:

```
FROM Demographics
inner join IndexPID on Demographics.NDoc_Number=IndexPID.NDoc_Number
inner join PatientSupply on Demographics.NDoc_Number=PatientSupply.NDocNum
```